# Is there a way in R to add a column for year that understands that there has been a turn of the year?

Tags: r, date, forecasting

I have a table that looks like the one below in R. In November 2017, I have forecasted values for December target weeks 50-53 and January weeks 1-4. I wish to add another column called target_year, that contains the year for the forecasted values, as in the table beneath the first table. Is there a way in R to add the correct year in the column?

In the actual data set, I am predicting 30 weeks ahead of time, and from forecast_years = 2015-2020 and forecast_months =  1:12.

I have:

| target_week | forecast_month | forecast_year | weekly_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 | 2017 | 0.011 |
| 2 | 11 | 2017 | 0.009 |
| 3 | 11 | 2017 | 0.011 |
| 4 | 11 | 2017 | 0.010 |
| 50 | 11 | 2017 | 0.005 |
| 51 | 11 | 2017 | 0.005 |
| 52 | 11 | 2017 | 0.007 |
| 53 | 11 | 2017 | 0.006 |

I wish to have:

| target_week | target_year | forecast_month | forecast_year | weekly_level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2018 | 11 | 2017 | 0.011 |
| 2 | 2018 | 11 | 2017 | 0.009 |
| 3 | 2018 | 11 | 2017 | 0.011 |
| 4 | 2018 | 11 | 2017 | 0.010 |
| 50 | 2017 | 11 | 2017 | 0.005 |
| 51 | 2017 | 11 | 2017 | 0.005 |
| 52 | 2017 | 11 | 2017 | 0.007 |
| 53 | 2017 | 11 | 2017 | 0.006 |

Answer (score 0):

Create a logical condition to add the column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
    mutate(target_year = case_when(target_week < 50 ~ 
       as.integer(forecast_year + 1), TRUE ~ forecast_year), .before = 2)
```

-output

```
df1
  target_week target_year forecast_month forecast_year weekly_level
1           1        2018             11          2017        0.011
2           2        2018             11          2017        0.009
3           3        2018             11          2017        0.011
4           4        2018             11          2017        0.010
5          50        2017             11          2017        0.005
6          51        2017             11          2017        0.005
7          52        2017             11          2017        0.007
8          53        2017             11          2017        0.006
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(target_week = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 
53L), forecast_month = c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L
), forecast_year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
2017L, 2017L), weekly_level = c(0.011, 0.009, 0.011, 0.01, 0.005, 
0.005, 0.007, 0.006)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Thank you! But in the actual data set, I am predicting 30 weeks ahead of time, and from forecast_years = 2015-2020 and forecast_months = 1:12. So I would have to have a code that works for a larger set of dates...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into the slider package.  It is date aware (to handle things like year ends and inconsistent days in a month) and basically enables forward and backward windowing.  Think of the basic case like allowing easy management of rolling sums and averages.  Here is an example that creates a rolling window of the current and previous month and executes a function against it.  If you are looking at fixed intervals (weeks), look at the block function.

```
library(slider)
m2 <- slide_index(t$data, t$month, ~ f(.x), identity, .before = ~.x %m-% months(1))
```